# How to add Gridded Reference Graphic widget in arcgis javascript api 4.14

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis-js-api

I am using arcgis javascript api 4.14. And I need to add this **Gridded Reference Graphic** widget in map application.
So can any one please provide me some reference or sample code so I can add this widget.
And in javascript api 4.14 I am not able to find this widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the widget or tool for the Web App Builder.

As far as I know it is not included in the API, so at least you are working with the Builder I don't think you can use it.

[Web AppBuilder Docs - grg widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-gridded-reference-graphic.htm)

[Solution grg Widget - Old repository](https://github.com/Esri/solutions-grg-widget)